# Trying to create a Teradata view to aggregate how long rows of a specific ID have had a certain value

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I have a test report table, that writes a row after each run of a test.

Let's say this is the data:

```
| main_id | status |  date   |
|---------|--------|---------|
|  123    |  pass  | Jan 1st |
|  123    |  fail  | Jan 2nd |
|  123    |  fail  | Jan 3rd |
|  123    |  fail  | Jan 4th |
```

I want to make a view that for each test, will list how long it has been failing.

Essentially, the corresponding row for the above data would look like this:

```
| main_id | days_failing |
|---------|--------------|
|  123    |      3       |
```

Using Teradata SQL, how could check each row in the source table, looking for the last success, and then sum up all the subsequent failures?

**Edit:** Note that there would be many different "main_id"s in the source table, I would need 1 row in the view for every unique failing test in the source table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      main_id
           ,count (*) - 1   as days_failing

from       (select      main_id
                       ,"date"

            from        t

            qualify     "date" >= max (case status when 'pass' then "date" end) over (partition by main_id)
            ) t

group by    main_id

order by    main_id
;
```

Comment: Hmmm...this (option 1) is getting close in that it does select only rows with failures, but it the days_failing field only gets populated with 1, no matter how many days of failing instances a test has. This may be important, but my date field is actually a timestamp, I just streamlined it for this question.

Comment: @user1029167 , The query counts the number of rows after the last 'pass'. It does not make since that you get always 1 unless this is indeed your data

Comment: @user1029167. Great :-) Since this is a correct answer please mark it as such. Thanks

Comment: @user1029167 also please notice that only main_id with at least 1 'pass' will be displayed. Is that O.K. by you?